# Unable to get the height of a UILabel with numberOfLines = 0

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, height

When I set a text to my label and check `myLabel.frame.size.height` I get always the same value, as if being always a single line, even if the text I set takes multiple lines... How could I get the "final" height?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try it inside your View Controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` function:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print(myLabel.frame.size.height)
}
```

Your label won't have it's final size until then.